# The assembly code (x86) with jumps and a syscall read function

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, system-calls

I would like to ask anyone for help with understanding an assembly code. My problem is:
the code after the label L2 is important, it calls subroutine function. But it seems to me that the program would never get to the code after label L2, because according to me syscall read (after L1) always reads 0 and after compare it to 1. But zero never equals one, so it seems to me the program never jumps to L2. I guess I must be wrong. I would really appreciate any help

```
jmp L1
L2:
movzbl -0x11(%ebp), %eax
movsbl %al, %eax
mov %eax, (%esp)
call SUBROUTINE_FNC
<...>

L1:
mov $0x0, %ebx
lea -0x11(%ebp), %ecx
mov $0x1, %edx
mov $0x3, %eax
int $0x80
mov %eax, -0x10(%ebp)
cmpl $0x1, -0x10(%ebp)
je L2
```

Comment: I'm guessing we're talking Linux syscalls, but you may want to add the OS to the tags.

Answer (score 1):

The syscall corresponds to [read](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and it looks like you are trying to read one byte at a time. `read` should return the number of actual bytes read, so if the call is successful then you will get a return value of 1, the compare will be true, and you will jump to L2, i.e.

```
L2:
SUBROUTINE_FNC(...);

if (read(fd, buff, 1) == 1) // read one byte
    goto L2;                // if one byte read then loop to L2
```

or, in a more structured form:

```
while (read(fd, buff, 1) == 1)
{
    SUBROUTINE_FNC(...)
}
```

Comment: +1 Assuming Linux `eax = syscall number (3)
ebx = file descriptor
ecx = pointer to buffer to read to
edx = number of bytes to read (1)`.